# Where is the recursion, in the minimax-decision algorithm?

Tags: heuristics, game-theory, board-games

The below is from an article titled:

> **Minimax: Recursive Implementation**

[image]

To be a recursive function, [you need to call yourself](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=72hal4Cp_2I&feature=player_detailpage#t=23).

- What part of this pseudo code is calling itself?
- How does depth-first effect the recursion process?
- There seems to be a return in every line of `minimax-value`,
  shouldn't the return be only on a terminal case?
- Will `value[op]` contain the moves in order from the root node?
- What does `Apply(op,game)` do the very first time through?

Any pointers are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Don't use images as main content of your post. Not only is it lazy, it also makes your question impossible to search and inaccessible to the visually impaired; [we don't like that](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/752/should-we-do-anything-about-questions-that-are-just-a-scan-of-a-problem-in-their). Please transcribe text and maths (note that you can [use LaTeX](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/271/add-short-reference-for-latex-commands)) and don't forget to give proper attribution to your sources!

Comment: You sure have an awful lot of questions in this post.  We ask people to stick to one question per question.  Also, we expect you to make a serious effort before asking here.  What have you tried?  Have you tried working through a small example by hand, manually simulating the algorithm?  You would probably find that very helpful in enabling you to answer many of your own questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside the function Minimax-Value, see the line where it says "the highest Minimax-Value of..."?  That is implicitly a recursive call to the Minimax-Value function, i.e., a call to yourself.